# How do I always include all Navigations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-8

I am new to EF Core, but used Xpo before.

I would like to always get the whole object with its subobjects from the database, but in EF Core it seems to be a bit tricky.

Here a simplified version of the `DbContext` class:

```
public class RemoteDbContext(DbContextOptions<RemoteDbContext> options) : IdentityDbContext<User, IdentityRole<int>, int>(options)
{
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DeliveryNote> DeliveryNotes { get; set;}
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        IEnumerable<IMutableEntityType> entites = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes();
        IEnumerable<IMutableNavigation>? navigations = null;

        foreach (var entity in entites)
        {
            navigations = entity.GetNavigations();

            foreach (var navigation in navigations)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType).Navigation(navigation.Name).AutoInclude();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested that `AutoInclude` example above in a smaller project before and it worked. But after putting it into a slightly bigger project I got the following error:

> Cycle detected while auto-including navigations: 'Order.ArticlePositions', 'Article.DeliveryNote', 'DeliveryNote.Order'
> To fix this issue, either don't configure at least one navigation in the cycle as auto included in `OnModelCreating` or call 'IgnoreAutoInclude' method on the query.

Here are the simplified model classes of `Order`, `Article` and `DeliveryNote`, to keep the snippets short:

```
public class Order
{
    private int id;
    [Key]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private List<Article> articlePositions = new List<Article>();
    public List<Article> ArticlePositions
    {
        get { return articlePositions; }
        set { articlePositions = value; }
    }

    public int ArticleCount => ArticlePositions != null? ArticlePositions.Count : 0;

    private List<DeliveryNote> deliveryNotes = new List<DeliveryNote>();
    public List<DeliveryNote> DeliveryNotes
    {
        get { return deliveryNotes; }
        set { deliveryNotes = value; }
    }

    // Non-Nullable on Key-Id marks required relation
    private int customerId;
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Customer))]
    public int CustomerId
    {
        get { return customerId; }
        set { customerId = value; }
    }

    private Customer customer = null!;
    public Customer Customer
    {
        get { return customer; }
        set { customer = value; }
    }

    private decimal totalPrice;
    [Precision(20, 2)]
    public decimal TotalPrice
    {
        get { return totalPrice; }
        set { totalPrice = value; }
    }
}
```

```
public class Article
{
    private int id;
    [Key]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string? name;
    public string? Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private decimal price;
    [Precision(20,2)]
    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }

    // Nullable on Key-Id marks optional relation
    private int? deliveryNoteId;
    [ForeignKey(nameof(DeliveryNote))]
    public int? DeliveryNoteId
    {
        get { return deliveryNoteId; }
        set { deliveryNoteId = value; }
    }

    private DeliveryNote? deliveryNote;
    public DeliveryNote? DeliveryNote
    {
        get { return deliveryNote; }
        set { deliveryNote = value; }
    }

    private int? orderId;
    [ForeignKey (nameof(Order))]
    public int? OrderId
    {
        get { return orderId; }
        set { orderId = value; }
    }

    private Order? order;
    public Order? Order
    {
        get { return order; }
        set { order = value; }
    }
}
```

```
public class DeliveryNote
{
    private int id;
    [Key]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private List<Article> articlePositions = new List<Article>();
    public List<Article> ArticlePositions
    {
        get { return articlePositions; }
        set { articlePositions = value; }
    }

    // Non-Nullable on Key-Id marks required relation
    private int orderId;
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Order))]
    public int OrderId
    {
        get { return orderId; }
        set { orderId = value; }
    }

    private Order order = null!;
    public Order Order
    {
        get { return order; }
        set { order = value; }
    }
}
```

When I now call somewhere else:

```
var berndsFirstOrder = RemoteDbContext.Orders.Where(order=>order.Customer.Contact.Firstname == "Bernd").FirstOrDefault();
```

I get the mentioned error.

I see the `AutoInclude` method takes a bool as a parameter.
Is there a way to detect a cycle before and then call `AutoInclude(false)` on that navigation?

Or do you know of other attempts to load an object with all its properties ans sub-objects/sub-collections filled (navigations and collections) from the database every time?

I know the AutoInclude might not be the best solution so I will be open to other options.

Currently I am using this in Blazor with .NET Core 8.

Comment: You are using Entity which is creating a mapping between the c# classes/properties and the database tables/fields.  The model creating is performing a migration (either create or update) which takes the c# classes and creates the database.  The error you are getting is the model (c# classes) contains a circular reference.  The error message is telling you circular reference is with the properties 'Article.DeliveryNote' and 'DeliveryNote.Order'.  So you can fix the circular reference instead of ignoring like the error message says.  The only way of detecting error is getting the error and fix.

Comment: So, in general, the code in OnModelCreating might be the wrong approach?
At first I was surprised, that, when I loaded objects with `RemoteDbContext.Orders.ToList()`, the navigation properties and collections were null/empty.
Then I thought they will be loaded every-time, when I use the AutoInlcude() approach.

Maybe I missed a special Attribute, which marks properties to be force-loaded?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes up because you have a denormalized, cyclic reference in your entity definitions. Orders have a Article, Article has a DeliveryNote, then DeliveryNote has an Order. Even if this *should* always reference the same original order, it is not guaranteed with, and you would not need to eager load DeliveryNote.Order. (The entity is already tracked) `AutoInclude` is geared towards scenarios where specific relationships are nearly always needed. It is not advisable to use `AutoInclude` to default to eager loading an entire object graph every time.

A simple fix would be to remove the de-normalized relationship. (DeliveryNote.Order) A better solution would be to look at using projection for reads. Eager loading an entire object graph should be a fairly rare scenario in EF. Where reads can be serviced by projection (`Select` or Automapper etc. `ProjectTo`) and updates are structured to be reasonably atomic so a more direct set of data can be queried when doing an insert or update operation.